# Mosaic Raster using GDAL Warp

Tags: gdal

I want to mosaic a set of rasters using **gdalwarp**. I know I can first build a **vrt** and then use **gdalwarp** but, I have no idea if is it possible to do it without using **vrt** files? I also know about **gdal_merge.py** tool but I do not want to use this tool too. Is there any other method to do it?

Comment: You don't need .vrt. The input is a long list of file names (much as there is for gdalbuildvrt)  http://gdal.org/gdalwarp.html  The asterisk (*) after srcfile indicates one or many, as it does with other arguments.